# Tracking a Row's "last updated by"

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate and I have a table that is constantly updated by various users logged in a web application. I would want to add "last updated by" and a "last update time" columns in that table. For the timestamp bit, I can simply use a trigger and fetch the time/date from oracle but for the "last updated by", the data should be fetched from the application layer.

One way to do is would be to explicitly identify all the scenarios where that entity is being modified and add a entity.setLastUpdatedBy(username) or something of that sort but this would mean that I have to identify all such scenarios where the entity might get modified.

Is there any other way I can achieve that?

ps: my problem is strikingly similar to [this problem](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=950834) but I could not find the answer to it. The link mentioned in the problem does not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a Spring and JPA user, [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) has exactly what you need: [*2.6. Auditing*](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.auditing):

> Most applications will require some form of auditability to track when an entity was created or modified and by whom.

All you have to do is:

- implement `Auditable` interface that basically exposes modification columns
- implement simple `Auditor` interface to let framework know who is currently logged-in:

  ```
  public interface AuditorAware<T, ID extends Serializable> {

      T getCurrentAuditor();
  }
  ```